# Full centering problem with angular sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm just getting started with angular. I am using a toolbar and sidenav as below. just as i want it. But the page I opened appears at the bottom. How can I reveal this? i.e. I want it to appear under "test button". How can I achieve this?

[image: How can I get the material-demands page here under the button?]

How can I solve the problem here?

Since I'm just starting out, I'm already waiting for your support.

```
<!-- Sidenav -->
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="push" [(opened)]="opened">Menu
    <app-side-nav-list >
    </app-side-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>

<!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">

  <button mat-icon-button (click)="opened=!opened" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>

  <span>Management mail panel</span>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>



<div class="content" role="main">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Test button</button>
  <i class="fa fa-user-cog "></i>
</div>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Put content you open in div class = "content" under <button> to be in same <div>

Comment: check styles for `.content` class, it looks like it takes the full available space